# c++ - does declering inherited abstract method inherited from abstract class has any performance issues?

Tags: c++, performance, abstract-class

I've got 3 classes

```
class GrandParent
{
    virtual int GrandParentMethod() = 0;
};

class Parent : public GrandParent
{
    virtual int ParentMethod() = 0;
    virtual int GrandParentMethod() = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    int ParentMethod() { return 1; }
    int GrandParentMethod() { return 0; }
};
```

My question is: Declering `GrandParentMethod` in `Parent` class makes it easier to implement `Child` class after some time (just need to check one header for abstract methods), but does it have any performance (memory? cpu?) issue?

Comment: It only have impact on the compilation process, none during runtime. And if you document the classes properly, then you shouldn't need the `GrandParentMethod` declaration in the `Parent` class either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no performance or CPU implications for your application since the method is abstract, although compilation may take fractionally longer as more code has to be read.

But do consider that this is not common idiomatic C++ practice and may end up *confusing* some of your code readers/maintainers. Additionally by re-declaring it at the `Parent` level you have one more place to change (or risk accidentally hiding a method) if for example the signature of the `Grandparent` method ever changes.

Comment: *…if the signature of the Grandparent method ever changes.* -- one should consider using `override`

Comment: @justin Many shops are only partially using C++11 or even not at all.

Comment: i am in the 'partially' camp. i enable this when support is present (for most targets). to be clear, it wasn't to say anything was wrong with your answer (which i +1'ed). it was only supplemental info -- "one should **consider** using `override`"

Answer (score 0):

You might run into design issues (eg: you would not have a another enum 
reflecting a enum of a base class). Another issue is, a abstract function can
have an implementation.

```
struct A {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
void A::f() {}

struct B : A {
    virtual void f() override = 0;
};

struct X : A {
    // Delegates to A::f, which is well defined
    virtual void f() override { return A::f(); }
};

struct Y : B {
    // Delegates to B::f, which is a 'undefined reference'.
    virtual void f() override { return B::f(); }
};
```

There are no performance issues, though.